# xcode ios: prepareForSegue - same data 2 display. 2nd display data error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm in the process of learning to use the storyboard to create tables.

When user Tabs on the cell, it goes to View A, while if user Tabs on the arrow icon on the right inside the cell it goes to View B.

Both A & B are to display the same data, just the layout is different. I'm using UIViewController for A and UITableViewController for B. Its just having different layout but same data.

The problem I have is that, view A shows the correct data for each cell, but view B always shows the data of cell[0] no matter which cell I Tab on.

The prepareForSegue code is as follow:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
`if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
{
    CarDetailViewController *detailViewController =
    [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                                indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];

    detailViewController.carDetailModel = @[_carMakes[row],
    _carModels[row], _carImages[row]];
}
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"niceDetails"])
{
    StaticTableViewController *detailViewController =
    [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                                indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];

    detailViewController.carDetailModel = @[_carMakes[row],
    _carModels[row], _carImages[row]];
}
}
```

Can someone point out where's the error here?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And otherwise check the data in the StaticTableViewController.
Are you synchronising the data etc?